# What do you think about the omnipresent "Test, Test, Test!" principle?

Tags: debugging, testing

In the old days programming used to involve less guesswork. I would write some lines of code and be 100% certain about what the code does and what it does not at a glance. Errors were mostly typos, but not about the functionality.

The last years I believe there is a trend for this "trial-and-error" programming : write the code (as if in draft), and then debug iteratively until the program's behavior appears to comply with the requirements. Test, and test again, and then again.
Funny thing is, in my Visual Studio the "Run" button has been replaced by a button labelled "Debug" (= I know you have some bugs!). I have to admit that in several apps that I write I cannot guarantee a bug-free code.

What do you think ? Or maybe our systems are now overly complicated (browser/OS/Service Pack compatibilities, etc etc) and this justifies testing on all types of environments.

Comment: While many people get pretty carried away with unit testing, you cannot guarantee bug-free code in any situation. If you think that you can, then you are delusional.

Comment: " I would write some lines of code and be 100% certain about what the code does and what it does not at a glance." You must have written some very simple programmes then!

Comment: I think this should be a wiki.

Comment: Why do you think this is a new phenomenon? It's the reason Edit-and-Continue was created!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one word answer is "Complexity".  The real answer is "Unnecessary Complexity"!
The accounting principles has not changed for the past 30 years.  Why then is writing an accounting system is so much more difficult today?  It is good to have a Graphic User Interface but do we have to go overboard?

Software development has been caught in a vicious circle for many years.  The complexity is feeding itself and instead of reducing it we simply hide it under layers and layers of wrappers.  Eventually something is going to give.

When we favor form over function, we have to pay the price.

Comment: What? No accounting package is complete without at least quarterly updates to incorporate new laws and rules. Also, they DO provide much more functionality than in 1980.

Answer (score 9):

I've experienced the opposite, actually. Whereas it used to be a case of running until it worked, I now unit test until the tests pass... and this seems to be at least a *reasonably* common transition, as far as I can see.

I have to say that code which worked first time with only typos has *never* been the norm in my experience. The difference is that now I can find the problems much more quickly, and also spot if old problems come back. I can sometimes manage pretty short and simple bits of code with no errors (and posting on Stack Overflow has improved that ability) but large, complex systems? Heck no.

To answer the title of your post - the "test, test, test" principle is a good one, in my view... but I don't associate that with running the whole program repeatedly. I associate it with running unit tests frequently. I rarely need to use the debugger for unit tests - usually a failure makes the cause suitably obvious by inspection, because only a small amount of code is being tested.

Comment: Trial-and-error unit testing is fine - it's when an entire application or system is developed by trial and error methods that you run into problems. When you implement a single class or method, the testing surface is usually relatively small - and hopefully doesn't involve to many interactions or dependencies with other bits of code. The same is not true of a complete system - this is where good planning, design, and code review make a huge difference - IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that in later years developers have come to the realization that the "100% certainty" might not actually be correct? Developing software is very complex, and even though the tools have evolved over the years, so has our realization that writing good code is hard. True, debugging and automated unit tests have made us more productive, but we still produce bugs, just as we did back then, only now we have different tools to catch them with.

Answer (score 4):

You may write code that you think you know 100% what it does and does not do, but there is always that edge case that you haven't thought of or the odd exception thrown that you don't expect.  Some times trial-and-error programming can be a helpful tool to narrow down a problem, with the debuggers help.

Its important to know what tools are available to you to help produce code with minimal bugs.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that the Test-Test approach helps me design the code. Sometimes the work that has to be done is too complex to do it all in one. Testing forces me to split it into smaller parts and as I solve these I am able to put them together into a larger whole.

Comment: +1. For me, unit tests is a fantastic way of thinking of your code in more details, and really analyze what you want it to actually do before you write it.

Comment: +1 Test-Driven Development is not a testing technique, it's a design technique

Answer (score 4):

I think the advantage comes in an indirect way: When you embrace tests  and unit tests, you have to write your application in such a way that you can actually write tests:

- Classes need to be written in such a way that you can instantiate a single object without the whole application and OS around it, but just a few helper objects. This means you need to minimize the dependencies, and make all communication to the surrounding system explicit.
- Implementing the test cases means that you have to find a minimum sequence of commands and calls that makes your class do something meaningful. This often points to awkward design decisions, or shows you that classes are very difficult to use for certain purposes.

All in all, when you embrace tests, you end up with a system that has a minimum of interdependencies between its components, and the test cases serve as documentation of how to use your components.

Answer (score 3):

Testing (executing your system) tells you something about "the presence of bugs but NOT about the absence of them" (afaik this term is coinced by dijkstra). It points to the direction that the strength of your test-suite is the key of testing: "You have so many test cases, that you can say, that many bugs do not exist. This implies that big parts of your software work as expected".

Some examples for having a strong/mighty test-suite:

- A lot of code is executed by your unit tests (the traditional coverage term)
- You have no false-negative tests (test which show green but in fact should be red). False negative tests are evil, because they give you a wrong sense of test-case quality. For details of good test-asserts and false-negatives see also [blog-entry#1](http://www.aldana-online.de/2008/03/18/ensure-test-suite-quality-and-beware-of-the-green-bar/) and [blog-entry#2](http://www.aldana-online.de/2008/06/16/xunit-test-errors-false-positives-false-negative/).
- The requirements are well understood (I have seen a lot of cases where an automated test was testing the wrong thing and the developer misunderstood the requirement from business). For the developer is was green, but for business the system was not working as expected (another kind of false-negative example but on a higher level).

In a sense the correctness of a program is only proven, when it is done with mathematical proofs (which only pays off for life-critical and money-intense systems). Still you can achieve a lot with automated testings (apart from unit-testing, automated integration testing always helped a lot).

Regarding debugging: I use debugging to as often as I used to be, but sometimes when adding new functionality to code (my new test-case shows green) I break other test-cases. By the assert I instantly see that something went wrong, but still didn't locate the bug. For locating the bug debugging is still helpful (with the red test-case I execute the problematic code-paths, with the debugger I locate the bug).

If you're interested in test-automation have a look at masterpiece [xUnit Test patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/).

Comment: By writing tests, rather than concentrating on code, "the developer misunderstood the requirement from business" is less like to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I've read one book ("TDD by example" by Kent Beck) which indeed seems to take that "trial and error" approach to an extreme: but it's more like "make the unit tests work". Still, I couldn't get myself to finish this book - a rare occurence, especially since I really hoped to get a better understanding. Still, committing obviously imbecile code to be improved later makes me shiver.

**Science:** Automated tests have their advantages. However, they are not the silver bullet they are claimed to be. No single test method is sufficient to findenough defects, and other methods have a better detection rate.

**Gut feel:** Our problems are facets of ever-increasing complexity. Complexity highly correlates with the amount of code we have to manage. In this light, TDD attempts to solve the problems of *to much code* by writing *even more code*.

**Advantages:** We now have an established formalism to make testing repeatable, accountable and immediately documented. It is definitely a way out of the "works on my machine" and "strange, it worked yesterday, I'll give you the latest DLL" trap.

Answer (score 0):

I currently practice Test Driven Development (TDD), or at least write many unit tests to verify that most/all of my code behaves the way I expect it to behave.  Taking this approach forces me to look at my program from the perspective of the consumer.  Also, as I write tests, I often think of boundary limits, additional scenarios that I didn't originally envision, etc.

I've now come to the point where I'm afraid to make changes to older programs, as I'm afraid that I'll break something.  Regression testing is onerous, compared with running a suite of unit tests.